# No call to copy constructor as expected

Tags: c++, constructor, copy-constructor

I have some code like this:

```
int a = 5;
Foo *foo = new Foo(MoreFoo(a),
    Bar(a));

// Foo CTOR:
Foo(MoreFoo mf, Bar bar): MoreBar(&mf,bar){}
```

My compiler gives me an error of type:

```
no matching function for call to ‘Bar::Bar(Bar)’
note: candidates are:
note: Bar::Bar(Bar&)
no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘Bar’ to ‘Bar&’
```

The error obviously relates to the code `Bar(a)`. Obviously `Bar` has appropriate CTOR and CCTOR. I understand why the compiler complains about trying to invoke something like `Bar::Bar(Bar)`, I'm creating a nameless variable (`Bar(a)`) which has to be copied during the call to the `Foo` constructor, but then shouldn’t it just invoke `Bar` CCTOR? Why am I getting the error?

Edit:

Why would you ever want to invoke `Bar::Bar(Bar)` instead of `Bar::Bar(Bar&)`?

Comment: Change `Bar::Bar(Bar &)` to `Bar::Bar(const Bar &)`.

Comment: Careful with passing `&mf`, since `mf` will die quite soon.

Comment: Please give a minimum compiling example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Temporaries cannot be bound to references unless they are references-to-`const`.

Comment: But then do you have any ideas why the complaint of the compiler is not `no matching function for call to ‘Bar::Bar(const Bar)’`  ?

Comment: @AlexandruBarbarosie: Is the compiler supposed to magically guess that you meant for a conversion-to-reference to exist in the language? It's looking for what you tell it to look for, and not finding it.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you declatred the copy constructor of class Bar the following way

```
Bar( Bar & );
```

But you need to declare it as

```
Bar( const Bar & );
```

if you want to use as an argument a temporary object because temporary objects may not be bound to non-const references.

Comment: It is a fact, even the compiler says so. What does the OP need to do to correct this error, now ?

Comment: @Chnossos I have not enetered the message yet.:) I have pressed Enter key by mistake.:)

Comment: @Alexandru Barbarosie  The compiler found the copy constructor but in could not convert the argument.